# Definir estilo CSS para campos já preenchidos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte função em javascript:

```
 $('input').blur(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.val())
    $this.addClass('used');
  else
    $this.removeClass('used');
});
```

ela adiciona a classe `used` ao elemento `input` clicado caso o mesmo tenha valor, se não, ao perder o foco ele fica sem a classe `used`. funciona corretamente porem esses campos são preenchidos com um valor que vem do banco de dados, e como não ocorre o ***click*** no input ele não adiciona a classe `used`, como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao abrir seu HTML, verifique todos os `input`s e adicione `used` a cada um que esteja preenchido usando [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='text']").each(function( index ) {
        if ($this.val())
            $this.addClass('used');
        else /* Este else é opcional. */
            $this.removeClass('used');
    });
});
```

Comment: pow perfeito! muito obrigado! funcionou!